# Mistune Markdown parser only matches the first occurance of my emoji pattern

Tags: python, regex, markdown, emoji

I have been trying to add a 'emoji' grammar to [mistune (markdown parser in python)](https://github.com/lepture/mistune) but unfortunately I haven't been successful with it. I am not that experienced with regex'es so there might be something wrong with mine but I just can't figure out what. Mine is a bit based off of the ones I've found in [mistune](https://github.com/lepture/mistune/blob/master/mistune.py#L441). The problem is, that mistune will only match the first pattern (like, literally the first in a block) and every emoji pattern after the first match is handled as a normal text. This is the code I've come up with:

```
import re
import mistune

class EmojiRenderer(object):
    def emoji(self, text):
        return "<emoji>%s</emoji>" % text


class EmojiInlineLexer(mistune.InlineLexer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EmojiInlineLexer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.default_rules.insert(0, "emoji")
        self.rules.emoji = re.compile(r'^:([a-zA-Z0-9\+\-_]+):', re.I)

    def output_emoji(self, m):
        text = self.output(m.group(1))
        return self.renderer.emoji(text)


class MarkdownRenderer(mistune.Renderer, EmojiRenderer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MarkdownRenderer, self).__init__(**kwargs)


renderer = MarkdownRenderer()
inline = EmojiInlineLexer(renderer=renderer)
markdown = mistune.Markdown(renderer=renderer, inline=inline)
demo_text = """
:thumbs_up: *this works*

this doesn't work :thumbs_down:

:smile: :cry:ing
"""
print(markdown(demo_text))
```

and this is the output:

```html
<p><emoji>thumbs_up</emoji> <em>this works</em></p>
<p>this doesn't work :thumbs_down:</p>
<p><emoji>smile</emoji> :cry:ing</p>
```

but the expected output should be

```html
<p><emoji>thumbs_up</emoji> <em>this works</em></p>
<p>this doesn't work <emoji>thumbs_down</emoji></p>
<p><emoji>smile</emoji> <emoji>cry</emoji>ing</p>
```

I would really appreciate any input/help.

Comment: you use `^` which means `start of string/line`

Comment: @Fallenhero Still the same output. I have tried a few variations of the regex but all of them had the same result (or didn't even match).

Comment: @Fallenhero actually, Mistune alters the text by striping already matched text off the front of the string so every regex must start with `^` to force it to start at the beginning of the string. See [the code](https://github.com/lepture/mistune/blob/master/mistune.py#L563).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python but this should work (at least it does on regex101)

```
:([a-zA-Z0-9\+\-_]+):
```

see https://regex101.com/r/iFHgTZ/1